# jQuery $(this) does not work at all in my codes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

jQuery $(this) does not work at all in my codes, here are the codes. The codes sending from my HTML is an image's onlick 'vote', located in a tb element of table.

```js
function vote(type, value, musicId) {
  var dataFields = {
    'type': type,
    'value': value,
    'musicId': musicId
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/voting.php",
    data: dataFields,
    timeout: 3000,
    success: function(dataBack) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(255,255,0,0.7)");
    },
    error: function() {
      $('#message').text('Problem!');
    }
  });
}
```

HTML & PHP codes:

```html
echo '<td class="up"><img class="liked" onclick="vote(\'liked\', \'1\', '.$single_music['id'].'); return false;" src="img/layout/like.png"></td>';

 echo '<td class="down"><img class="favorite" onclick="vote(\'favorite\', \'1\', '.$single_music['id'].'); return false;" src="img/layout/favorite.png"></td>';
```

What i want to do?

Because there are multiple items generated from database, and i want to let the jquery tell them apart when i click the vote image in some item.

Could you please help me find where the error is? Thanks.

Comment: I removed the snippet. It makes no sense when there's nothing to execute.

Comment: The problem why the solutions below won't work is because you're using the `onclick` attribute. When the `vote()` function is executed the value of `this` will already be `window`. As you're already using jQuery you should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead - like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbgmh2p2/1/) with a modified version of your markup+script

Answer (score 3):

`this`, in your callback, is `window`. The usual solution is to save the external `this` in a variable.

But part of your problem is you're inlining event handlers and not passing the element so `this`, in `vote`, isn't even the element. The best solution would be to avoid using inlining javascript (for example set data-attributes with the relevant music id) but a working solution would be this:

```js
function vote(element, type, value, musicId) {
    var dataFields = {'type': type, 'value': value, 'musicId': musicId};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/voting.php",
        data: dataFields,
        timeout: 3000,
        success: function(dataBack){
                $(element).css("background-color","rgba(255,255,0,0.7)");
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#message').text('Problem!');
        }
    });
}

echo '<td class="down"><img class="favorite" onclick="vote(this, \'favorite\', \'1\', '.$single_music['id'].'); return false;" src="img/layout/favorite.png"></td>';
```

Comment: Or using [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the value of `this`

Comment: @Andreas yes. TBH it would be more useful to find a more complete existing QA and close this one as duplicate...

Comment: It looks like the context isn't the right one in the vote function either. How are you calling it ?

Comment: `<... onclick="vote(...)">` so `this` in `vote()` already is the `window`

Comment: @Andreas I edited for this new information

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution to Denys would be to pass `this` as the context

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/voting.php",
    data: dataFields,
    timeout: 3000,
    context: this, // <-----
    success: function(dataBack) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(255,255,0,0.7)");
    },
    error: function() {
      $('#message').text('Problem!');
    }
});
```

In your example thought it's hard to figure out what exactly `this` is because we don't know what context you're using it in.

If you're just calling the function then `this` refer's to `window` - and the `this` inside the ajax function refers to `window`

```
vote(a,b,c);
```

If you're passing the function in as a callback to an event handler then `this` refers to the element and the `this` inside the ajax success function refers to `window`. So you need to cache it or pass it as the context

```
$(element).on('click',vote)
```